# Move a question to another site

Tags: support, migration

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9394498/ssl-fingerprint-inconsistency-what-does-it-mean

I didn't think enough before posting and now I realize very few people could answer it on stackoverflow. I am sure it can get more attention on http://security.stackexchange.com.

Can you move it or should I just create a duplicate?

Thanks and very sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always flag your question, select "Other" and type in a request for a moderator to migrate your question. Note that they may ask the moderators on the new site whether it is valid, and even if it gets migrated there is no promise it will stay open.